# Upgrading to the master branch of pythonnet from github

Tags: c#, python, git, pip, python.net

I want to use a python code snipped inside a .NET class library, but got some Problems with pythonnet from github and upgrading to its 'master branch'. [Pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)

I already made an issue in github, but it got closed as off topic, because my knowledge about git, pip and so on is not the best. Besides this i was told that this topic would be better asked here on stackoverflow. [My Github issue](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/672)

This is the code sample, which should work, if i upgrade to the pythonnet master branch.

```
        string envPythonHome = @"C:\Python27";
        string envPythonLib = envPythonHome + @"\Lib\site-packages";

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", envPythonHome, 
        EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPythonHome + ";" + 
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine), 
        EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", envPythonLib, 
        EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        PythonEngine.PythonHome = envPythonHome;        <--- Exception here this time.
        PythonEngine.PythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH");

        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
            Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
        }
```

I tried getting the master branch with 'pip install git+https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet' but the cmd says the command 'git' was not found.
So I cloned the master branch with git bash --> 
'git clone https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet'.

Refering to the [Wiki](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation) i should run **'python setup.py bdist_wheel'** and 
**'pip install --no-index --find-links=./dist/'** from the cloned directory, but these two applications phyton and pip are located in the python install folder.
Should i copy them to the pythonnet folder or how am i supposed to do this?
Thanks in advance!